# How to convert a custom object into String in Android?

Tags: java, android, object, serialization

I have an Object of a custom class. I need to convert it into a String so that I can write it to a file. Is there a way out for this ?

thanks for help.

Comment: You want to implement the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Comment: please tell us what to do exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert a custom class into a `String` automatically. The system has no way of knowing how you want that `String` to be formatted, what exactly you want to be in it and such.

You have to manually implement a method in your custom class that returns the text interpretation of the object. Usually you would override a method called `toString()`. This method often gets called automatically if you provide an instance of your class to some methods. Let's say if you do `System.out.println(instance)`, then the `instance`'s `toString()` method is automatically invoked.

I don't know what your custom class is. But let's say it's something like a `Person` class with member variables `String name` and `int age`. Then the `toString()` method defined in the class could look something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Name: " + name + ", age: " + age;
}
```

This would provide an output like "Name: Some Name, age: 30".

Answer (score 0):

Try , using the `objectname.toString()` method.

Comment: This will not *convert* the object to a string.

Comment: If you at all want to do this then first you have to make sure that you are overriding the ToString() method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

To convert serialize object to String and String to Object

```
public static String beanToString(Object object) throws IOException {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    StringWriter stringEmp = new StringWriter();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
    objectMapper.writeValue(stringEmp, object);
    return stringEmp.toString();
}

public static <T> T stringToBean(String content, Class<T> valueType) throws IOException {
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(content, valueType);
}
```

And to save an object to a file

```
FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
os.writeObject(this);
os.close();
fos.close();
Loading (w/o exception handling code):

FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
SimpleClass simpleClass = (SimpleClass) is.readObject();
is.close();
fis.close();
```